# Cancel observable if another sequence emits

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have two observables, `hover$` and `unhover$`, triggered on hover and on blur respectively.

The `unhover$` has a `debounceTime(500)` to delay it from being too fast.

Now consider this timeline:

```
 [    0ms] hover triggered
 [   50ms] unhover 500ms debounce started
 [  100ms] hover triggered
 [  550ms] unhover triggered
```

How can I 'cancel' the first `unhover$` that is pending, when a new value is emitted by the `hover$` sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`takeUntil`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeUntil) to have your observable be unsubscribed if a notifier Observable emits a value.

Something like this:

```
unhover$
.debounceTime(500)
.switchMap(evt => Rx.Observable.of(evt)
  .takeUntil(hover$)
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```